# pg_rewind tries to rewind 1G even if the databases were identical few seconds ago

Tags: postgresql

I want to use `pg_rewind` to improve the time it takes to recover old master and turn it into slave.  However even if the new master and old master are few seconds apart (replication stopped few seconds ago), `pg_rewind` thinks it needs to sync 1293 MB.  After it finished the pg_rewind Postgres service fail to start and I need to do rysnc to fix it.  Is it a known bug with pg_rewind or I'm missing something.

```
2017-09-19 16:17:36: ++ ssh -T -o ConnectTimeout=5 postgres@172.18.255.5 '/usr/pgsql/bin/pg_rewind --progress  --source-server='\''port=5432 host=172.18.255.6'\'' --target-pgdata=/postgr$
2017-09-19 16:17:36: connected to server
2017-09-19 16:17:36: servers diverged at WAL position 1/88000000 on timeline 55
2017-09-19 16:17:36: rewinding from last common checkpoint at 1/871F3210 on timeline 55
2017-09-19 16:17:36: reading source file list
2017-09-19 16:17:36: reading target file list
2017-09-19 16:17:36: reading WAL in target
2017-09-19 16:17:36: need to copy 1293 MB (total source directory size is 1333 MB)
2017-09-19 16:17:48:       0/1324255 kB (0%) copied^M  28278/1324255 kB (2%) copied^M 142966/1324255 kB (10%) copied^M 257654/1324255 kB (19%) copied^M 372342/1324255 kB (28%) copied^M 487$
2017-09-19 16:17:48: creating backup label and updating control file
2017-09-19 16:17:48: syncing target data directory
2017-09-19 16:17:52: Done!
```

Comment: Log checkpoints and check your logs when the last common checkpoint was. Maybe `pg_rewind` is right.